# Accessing data in R using multiple column identifyers

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I am having an extremely difficult time finding an easy way to go about accessing data based on multiple columns identifying that data.

For example, I have data from multiple years, multiple plots and multiple samples within those plots and a parameter at the end (x, y). So my data headers look like this:

Year, Plot, Sample ID

I have many levels within each of those and I want to be able to quickly and easily plot those values for example in year=2015, plot=3 and Sample ID= C.

I have dabbled with code looking like this but when I start using it for functions it becomes clumsy, is there a more elegant way out there?

```
plot( x[Year=="2015" & Plot=="3" & Sample ID=="C"], 
      y[Year=="2015" & Plot=="3" & Sample ID=="C"]
)
```

Comment: First, get your data together, using `merge`, so that you have one data frame with x and y, not separate frames for each. If you're using base plots, `with` is your friend. `subset()` can also save a fair amount of typing (though `dplyr` is better). But you could do `with(subset(data, Year == "2015", Plot == "3", SampleID == "C"), plot(x, y))`.

Comment: Thank you Gregor, I forgot to mention that I had originally been sub setting the data, this required me to write a ton of code (for loops seem like a dangling carrot I can never reach). This also made so many attached objects that it made me feel cluttered. Perhaps cluttered is still the way to go.

Comment: Don't ever `attach`, it's a nasty habit. Do you just want to write out a bunch of plots (say, all combinations) to files? Your question made it seem like you want to do things interactively, but it you just want a script to kick out plots for every year, every plot, every Sample ID, that's a very different question.

Comment: I actually want to be able to do the latter, (kick out plots for every year, plot etc.). I think what it sounds like I need to do is setup for loops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's say your data looks like this:

```
base_data = expand.grid(Year = 2013:2015,
                        Plot = 1:3,
                        SampleID = LETTERS[1:3],
                        ObsID = 1:4)
n = nrow(base_data)
base_data$x = runif(n)
base_data$y = rnorm(n)
head(base_data)
#   Year Plot SampleID ObsID         x           y
# 1 2013    1        A     1 0.5504904  0.64624816
# 2 2014    1        A     1 0.5337804  0.08473398
# 3 2015    1        A     1 0.9584508  0.31683347
# 4 2013    2        A     1 0.0854122  0.61898020
# 5 2014    2        A     1 0.8061409 -0.46255868
# 6 2015    2        A     1 0.8764612  0.24384120
```

Next time you ask a question you should include code to create data or share your own data with `dput()`. Then there's no guesswork about how your data looks, what classes things are, etc.

Anyway, to plot y versus x for each Year, Plot, and SampleID. I like using `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
# first we group our data
group_by(base_data, Year, Plot, SampleID) %>%
    # then we "do" a function that saves a plot
    # within this function, `.` is an abbreviation for
    # the piece of the data frame that is one group
    do({
       # create a filename. Within a group, there is only
       #     one value each for year, plot, and sample ID
       #     so I'll just use the first row in the filename
       group_name = paste0("y", .[1, "Year"],
                           "-p", .[1, "Plot"],
                           "-s", .[1, "SampleID"])
       # initialize the file
       png(filename = paste0(group_name, ".png"))
       # draw the plot
       plot(.[["x"]], .[["y"]])
       # close the file
       dev.off()
       # dplyr will be happy if we return a data frame
       return(.)
    })
```

This should create a plot saved in your working directory for each combination of year, plot, and sample ID. I commented the code very thoroughly, but I'm going to repeat it again below, without comments, to emphasize that it's actually a very brief set of commands:

```
group_by(base_data, Year, Plot, SampleID) %>%
    do({
       group_name = paste0("y", .[1, "Year"],
                           "-p", .[1, "Plot"],
                           "-s", .[1, "SampleID"])
       png(filename = paste0(group_name, ".png"))
       plot(.[["x"]], .[["y"]])
       dev.off()
       return(.)
    })
```

Comment: This answered the question in a direct and helpful way. Recommendations were also provided to utilize >dput() for better directed questions.